# How to put logo at top right in latex letter

Tags: latex

From several posts, I have put together the following code for a letter. I want the logo on the letter on the top right of the first page of the letter. Currnetly my logo goes on its own page. Assistance will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newfloat{figure}{h!}{lof}
\floatname{figure}{Figure}

\signature{Your name}
\address{Company Name \\ Location \\ City}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./bird1.png}
\end{figure}
\hrulefill

\begin{letter}{The Director \\ Company \\ City}
\opening{\textbf{Subject: Subject}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adip-iscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\hrulefill

\ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
\encl{Enclosures.}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```